# How to plot near zero values with qgraph?

Tags: r, plot, r-qgraph

How can I plot very small/near zero values with the `qgraph`-package in R?

```
m <- matrix( data = c( 1, 0.5, 0.1, 0.01 ), ncol = 2 )

library( qgraph )
qgraph( input = m )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Experiment with the `cut` parameter.  Your small values are likely present, they are just hard to see.  Specifying `cut` adjusts the saturation width such that everything above the cut point have the strongest color intensity and everything below gets weaker the further it is from the cut point.  By making this close to 0, the near 0 values will be plotted with more saturated colors than they would have been otherwise.

```
qgraph(input=m,cut=0.05)
```

[image]